# Showing $u'=v$ a.e. given $u_k \to u$ and $u'_k \to v$ in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Suppose $(u_k)$ is a sequence of differentiable functions in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying

(1) There is a $u \in L_2(\mathbb{R})$ so that $\| u_k - u\|_2 \to 0$.

(2) There is a $v \in L_2(\mathbb{R})$ so that $\|u'_k - v \|_2 \to 0$.

If $u$ is differentiable, show that $u'=v$ almost everywhere.

This is a problem on a practice qualifying exam that I am having trouble with.

Comment: Do you know the Sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb R)$ and the fact that it is complete?

Comment: You can consider, $f(x) = u'(x) - u(x)$, Then check to see if it meets the hypothesis of Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem. Then use triangle inequality with Holder's inequality and Differentiation Theorem to deduce the desired conclusion.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I remember seeing that somewhere.  However, I'm assuming we can't use that fact since our list of topics to study doesn't have Sobolev spaces on it.

Comment: @akech Something that comes to mind from your hint is if I can show that $u' \in L_2(\mathbb{R})$, then $f$ will be locally integrable and will therefore satisfy the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @akech Oh silly me.  The function $u'$ is locally integrable by the fundamental theorem of calculus.  Since $u \in L_2(\mathbb{R})$ we have $u$ is also locally integrable, so $f(x)$ satisfies the hypothesis of the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $w(x) := \int_0^x v(t)\,dt$. Then $w$ is differentiable a.e. and $w' = v$ a.e. Let $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Then
$$
\langle u'-w',\varphi\rangle = \langle w-u,\varphi'\rangle = \langle w-u_k,\varphi'\rangle + \langle u_k-u,\varphi'\rangle.
$$
Now,
$$
\langle w-u_k,\varphi'\rangle = \langle u_k'-v,\varphi\rangle\to 0
$$
as $k\to\infty$. Therefore, and since $u_k\to u$ in $L^2$, we have $\langle u'-w',\varphi\rangle = 0$ for all $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$. Since $C_0^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, this shows $u' = w' = v$ a.e., which we had to prove.

Comment: So at the end of your proof you basically have $\langle u'- v , f \rangle =0$ for every $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.  It looks like you are saying that since $\langle  , \rangle$ is an inner product in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we have $[u'-v]=0$.  But for us to make this conclusion we need to know that $u'-v \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.  But we don't know if $u' \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.